# Cannot find module angular/animations

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-animations

I am using webpack in angular2 and when I try to run my app I get an error stating

> Cannot find module "@angular/animations"

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

My webpack.config.js file is

```
var htmlWebPack = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/main.ts",
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
          }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new htmlWebPack({
        template: './index.html'
    })
    ]
};
```

When I run the command like npm start, I get an error as mentioned above.

I even tried to install angular-animate using this command

> npm install angular-animate

This is the error message I get

[image]

I also tried to uninstall angular-animate with the command

> npm uninstall angular-animate

but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Perform below steps to make it work:

1. npm install @angular/animations@latest --save
2. import "BrowserAnimationsModule" from "@angular/platform-browser/animations" in your root NgModule (Without this, your code will compile and run, but animations will trigger an error)
3. In your component use imports from the new package like this - " import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations'; "

This worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You are on the right track, but just close! You can see in this [discussion here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15427), that animations was taken out of the core. Furthermore, hyphenated names are apparently being done away with - so angular animations is now @angular/animations, just as @angular/angular-cli has become @angular/cli.

So, in order to (hopefully) resolve your issue - you should do the following:

Update to Angular 4 in your project. You will need to run the following in order to do so: `npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest --save` and *you also need to update Typescript* with `npm install typescript@latest --save`

That should do the trick.

If it *does not* do the trick, I would suggest checking your json package and making sure you bumped up to 4.0 in all the core aspects along with the now separate animations segment. Then, delete your node modules folder, clear your cache, and run a clean install with the update package, like so:

```
>$  rm -rf node_modules
>$  npm cache clear
>$  npm install
```

It is a little hectic right now with a lot of different people contributing a lot of changes and fixes to the core feature set, and *then* other parts of Angular being caught up with the core, so I would advise moving forward carefully with any project you are on, in very methodical steps, so that you can address issues that come up one by one (and easier to find/fix).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @TobySpeight, I should have thought of that the first time! I put in as much helpful solution as I could think of at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

You must import angular animation module like this:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';import {trigger,state,style,animate,transition}from '@angular/animations';
```

Answer (score 2):

@angular/animimations was introduced in version 4.0.0 (release candidate). You'll need to update to angular4.

Comment: will updating to angular 4 effect my other setting ie. component and modules. or will uninstalling the angular/animation will work?

Comment: angular uses semantic versioning. They'll increment the major version (2 to 4) when there is some breaking change.  However, it is not a complete re-write like it was from ng1 to ng2.   Either remove the animations module or upgrade - both should work fine for you.

Comment: i have updated the question with the latest try, please have a look at it, thanks for your help

Comment: One of your libraries has a dependency on @angular4.  Which one? i'd uninstall that library.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in Angular 2 this was a part of core, as shown in the [archived documentation](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html):

`import {
  Component,
  Input,
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  animate
} from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 0):

I have done this steps:

https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1880#issuecomment-290557768

I'll quote:

> I had the same issue upgrading from 2.0 to 4.0. In the end I was missing the following from my systemjs.config.js:
>
> '@angular/animations':
> 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
> '@angular/animations/browser':
> 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
> '@angular/platform-browser/animations':
> 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
>
> At first I had the first and third line - everything started working
> once I added the second line for @angular/animations/browser.

this worked for me and i can see fixed most of cases.

Comment: Hi, where is it systemjs.config.js in an angular-cli project? Thanks

Comment: for angular-cli i think it doesn't exists.