# name can only contain URL-friendly characters NPM Install

Tags: angular, npm, angular8

I have a project and I'm trying to give npm install, but it is giving the following error:

```sh
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME npm ERR! Invalid package name "@
angular / platform-browser / animations": name can only contain
URL-friendly character`
```

I'm using Angular 8
My `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "cingo-render",<br>
    "version": "1.0.0",<br>
    "description": "Cingo-Render",<br>
    "author": "",<br>
    "license": "MIT",<br>
    "dependencies": {<br>
        "@angular/common": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/compiler": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/core": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/forms": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/http": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/router": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/animations": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/platform-browser/animations": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@angular/animations/browser": "~5.2.2",<br>
        "@types/node": "^7.0.11",<br>
        "@types/core-js": "^0.9.39",<br>
        "systemjs": "0.19.40",<br>
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",<br>
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",<br>
        "rxjs": "5.5.6",<br>
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4",<br>
        "typescript": "2.7.1",<br>
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.3.0",<br>
        "ngx-mask": "2.4.4",<br>
        "ngx-mydatepicker": "2.4.5",<br>
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "1.6.1",<br>
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",<br>
        "ngx-device-detector": "1.3.3"<br>
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43291326/1978254

Comment: Can you take a look at similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107455/name-can-only-contain-url-friendly-characters)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module angular/animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857345/cannot-find-module-angular-animations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your node version, I was encountering similar issues when using `10.**.??` and i upgraded to `15.11.0`.
then `npm i` worked fine