# I am getting error while "npm i ngx-slick-carousel" with angular 11

Tags: angular, npm-install

I am getting error while doing  "npm i ngx-slick-carousel --save"

**My versions are:**

```
$ npm -v
7.6.1

$ node -v
v14.17.0

Angular CLI: 11.2.13
```

**Errors are :**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: irt-official@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~11.2.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from ngx-slick-carousel@0.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel
npm ERR!   ngx-slick-carousel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\malik\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\malik\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-19T14_13_57_035Z-debug.log
```

**package.json:**

```
"@angular/animations": "~11.2.13",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.13",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.13",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.13",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.13",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.13",
"angular-animations": "^0.11.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.3"
```

Kindly help me with this issue. Why I am not able to install this.Thank you

***UPDATE 1:***

**I have deleted node_module and packagelock.json file and tried to do "npm install" and I am getting this errors now**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: irt-official@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~11.2.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"12.0.1" from @angular/animations@12.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@">=6.0.0" from angular-animations@0.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular-animations
npm ERR!     angular-animations@"^0.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\malik\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt
```

for a full report.

***UPDATE 2:***

**I have done "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" this command installed my node_module but when i do  "ng serve" after installing i am getting this error**

An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@angular/platform-browser/animations" has missing dependencies:

- @angular/animations
- @angular/animations/browser

***UPDATE 3:***

I have completely refreshed every thing like I have uninstalled node and angular cli and reinstalled

node version *16.2.0*

npm -v: 7.6.1

Angular CLI: 12.0.1

Now i have created new project "ng new IRT-Official"
Then Again i tried to do "npm install ngx-slick-carousel --save"
Now i am getting this error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: irt-official@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@12.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~12.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from ngx-slick-carousel@0.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-slick-carousel
npm ERR!   ngx-slick-carousel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to
```

***UPDATE 4:***

I have manually added  "ngx-slick-carousel": "0.5.1", in my packege.json file and then "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" it installed crousal but when i did all steps i am getting error like

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Comment: ok I am going to edit and share in textual form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I Have tried by running "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" But still same errors

Comment: try the following "npm install @angular/animations@latest --save", whenever you get a new error look it up in SO or google - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857345/cannot-find-module-angular-animations - moving from one error to another is progress

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez kindly check update 3 in question .

Comment: I have updated my answer with new information, you are missing two commands before installing `ngx-slick-carousel`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

It seems that you are not running the installation steps from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel

[image]

**PREVIOUS**

You package.json is looking for `"@angular/common": "~11.2.13"`
but you have installed version 11.2.14

Update your package.json to

```
   "@angular/common": "^11.2.13"
```

or

```
   "@angular/common": "^11.2.14"
```

[What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: I have tried but not working.Can you please help me on team viewer?

Comment: does the same error appear ? different error ? please update your question. (unable to help you remotly)

Comment: I have unInstalled Angular CLi and installed again now my angular cli version is 12.0.1
And I am updated my question for new errrors

Comment: I think I have issues with nodejs.. Becuase i have many project i have tried to "npm install" after deleted node_module and packagelock.json file I am not able to install in any project.Should i show you that errors even in this project too i am unable to do "npm install"

Comment: I am following these steps.I have no issues on first two installation but i have issue on third one ngx crousal installation

Comment: I am getting close to it.I am going to update 4 in my question

Comment: Wait, did you run the third step ? what was the output of that ? why are you adding something to package.json by hand ? did you try with --save-dev ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get around this by editing the in your node modules find the slick carousel folder and go to the package module there you can find the version history - you will need to update anywhere that you see version 9 and add 10 and 11.  the thing is though you have to also do security testing and unit testing against multiple pieces of code before you put this in production - or you should anyway, you probably should find a carousel module  that is kept up to date.

**anywhere you see @angular change it to below**

"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0"

Comment: Hello Dear.I have confirmed that my all things starting from @Angular are 11.2.13

Comment: no it should been slick carousel not your package.json for angular. 
 this error line tells us what the problem is @angular/common@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from ngx-slick-carousel@0.5.1

try and delete the node_modules folder and reinstall - because I looked at the git and it has the correct version trees - which means something is wrong with the install I think, sometimes things corrupt - angular is a finicky.

Comment: or npm install @angular/cli@11.2.14 @angular/common@11.2.14 ngx-slick-carousel@latest

Comment: nothing worked.Even I have tried with older versions of angular.Can you please help me using Team viewer?

Comment: I know that having and urgent matter and depend on written answer can be painful, but please dont ask for remote support, we are not a call center.

Comment: yes okay sorry.I am trying to keep my question update so i can get my output soon.

Comment: @ArslanMalik try to move to angular 12.  ng update @angular/cli --allow-dirty --force
then do the same for @angular/common